# Intellij Navigate to letter-Mnemonic Bookmark shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-13, intellij-12

What is the shortcut to navigate to a letter-Mnemonic Bookmark ?

Looking the [Official Intellij Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigation-between-bookmarks.html) ,  they just explains the shortcuts for the number-Mnemonic bookmarks.

PD: I would be nice to add Windows and Mac shortcuts.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you toggle your letter-mnemonic bookmark, you can then show the bookmarks pop-up using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and the type the letter of your bookmark you want to go to. After you type the letter it immediately opens editor at the corresponding bookmark.

Looking at the list of commands in *Settings/Keymap* I don't see a way to assign shortcut to specific letter-mnemonic bookmarks in the same way it works for number-mnemonic bookmarks, so this is probably the only way.

I verified that this solution works on both Windows and Linux version of IntelliJ 13. Hopefully it will work the same way on Mac version too.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried in Mac (with Android Studio) and is not working!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac so I can't test it :(. Could you verify that Show Bookmarks shortcut is set to SHIFT+F11 in Settings/Keymap on Mac? It might be different from Windows and Linux

Comment: The shortcut is ⌘+F3.

Comment: or ⌘+fn+F3 if you don't have the Function Keys activated by default.

Answer (score 3):

If your having an issue with Intellij's bookmarks F11 key not working on OSX, check your keyboard shortcuts for the Mac. I found F11 was enabled to show the desktop. The OS was intercepting the commands before Intellij, I disabled it under preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts and now bookmarks work. Of course this goes for any set of function keys, not just book marks.